# Has reducing MAC size and increasing message size the same effect on security?

Tags: hmac, mac, integrity, output-size

I am evaluating ways to reduce the overhead of (H)MACs on small messages. I was primarily wondering if there is a difference between halving the MAC length or keeping the same MAC length but using it to authenticate a message of twice the size.

My initial thought was that the message/MAC ration would be the same though then it occured to me that this is probably not the complete picture as each individual package would be simpler to attack. Therefore I would probably have to discard both packages if one if them fail an integrity check.

Is my last conclusion correct for them to behave identically or am I missing something?

Comment: MAC security is independent of message size.

Comment: You should be careful about truncating the MAC output, You may give huge advantage to the attacker. Still your question is not clear or wide to answer!

Comment: @kelalaka I was more thinking about shrinking the output by using a different Algo (e.g. SHA-512 → SHA-256) though I think SAI Peregrinus already cleared up my misunderstanding